# How to store assets and website content in local system in Magnolia CMS?

Tags: magnolia

I have created a website and uploaded images in assets module. I want to store my images and website content in my local system for backup. 
Does anyone know how to do that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Jackrabbit DataStore in order to that, basically you need to specify a threshold and Jackrabbit will automatically store them in your local data store.

For more information, have a look at: https://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/DataStore

Cheers,

Comment: Thank you Ducaz035 for reply. I am using database to store everything. I want to store images in a path or direct image store in local system. If I am giving local path in datastore I am missing my image in website. Kindly clarify me.

Comment: himm, If you do not want to store them via Jackrabbit but rather serve resources from file system, you can use resources servlet. https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS56/Resources this should help there.

Comment: Okay, this is great way and I have used it to store my light modules folder in local. Since I have my images in database and suppose it crash, how am I going to recover images uploaded directly from author. Do you have any way?

Comment: @TumpaSINGHARAY We have backup module which takes care of that, If database crashes you just need to restore it. https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS56/Backup+module